# How do I login to a website with C#?

Tags: c#, forms, .htaccess, authentication, screen-scraping

I need to login to a website with C#, but the website doesn't have a login form within the page it uses a htaccess style popup login. I have done this before, but only with a site which used a webpage form login. I have tried capturing the header data with live http headers, but I am not seeing the login post data.

How would I go about logging into one of these with C#?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```cs
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
  string page = wc.DownloadString("http://example.com/");
}
```